# m3u8 url not working with video.js 7.0 lib

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

Here is the live example give by video.js -> https://jsbin.com/gejugat/edit?html,output

I just pasted my m3u8 url but it is not working. I am not able to figure out if there is something wrong with m3u8 url.

here is m3u8 url

```
https://d2h15f8k35zmv7.cloudfront.net/output/875AE0BD-8A48-40B2-964F-31B2D91D49C6.m3u8
```

I also used hls.js (https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/), for it same url is working fine. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Console within chrome states a status of 'canceled' when i try to play it, maybe some DRM?